# Instagram API app after june 1 2016

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api

The Instagram new API policy have become super strict. They are not allowing fetching public content at all. We are literally following all Instagram policies and still cant get approval of public_content.

Is there any workaround or any possibility of fetching the data.

This is the response that I have recieved from instagram

> General issues:
>
> Policy Violation (Ad network, Influencer network, Other related): Your
>   app should not attempt to build an ad network on Instagram, nor
>   transfer any data that you receive from us (including anonymous,
>   aggregate, or derived data) to any ad network, data broker, influencer
>   network, or other advertising or monetization-related service. In
>   working to build a high quality platform, we ask that you comply with
>   our Platform Policy
>   (http://wwww.instagram.com/about/legal/terms/api/).

Comment: So you are saying that all the values should be in upper case of the URL..? What about the public_content. Is it PUBLIC_CONTENT or public_content?

Comment: No, I am saying to replace the Uppercase words by the correct values. i.e. 
`CLIENT_ID = your client id` or `ACCESSTOKEN = your access token`

Comment: This does not work as it says .. `{"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", "error_message": "You must include a valid client_id, response_type, and redirect_uri parameters"}`

Comment: Hi @NarayaN did you finally get instagram permissions? My instagram submission got rejected for the same reason - that we are trying to build an 'ad network', which we are not.

Comment: We got permission because we knew someone in facebook and we wrote to them. Its quite difficult to get permission now a days.

Comment: @MovinJain any tips how to get the instagram permissions? My application is getting rejected for the exact same reason and I'm not even granted basic access.

Comment: There was also a search engine called "HashtagPirate" by "ShootNowAimLater", which also died due to Instagram's APi handicap.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, they now grant permissions only to applications with some specific usage cases.
According to Instagram official website, these are:

1. To help **individuals share their own content** with 3rd party apps
2. To help **brands and advertisers** understand and manage their audience and digital media rights
3. To help **broadcasters and publishers** discover content, get digital rights to media, and share media with proper attribution

Note that in order to get `public_content` permission, you need to fall under the 2nd or the 3rd use case. Otherwise, consider changing your application / service in such way that is now uses `basic` permission and acquires only your users' media.

There is no **valid and legal** possibility to fetch public data except for successful passing the Instagram permission review.

This [official developer documentation page](https://instagram.com/developers/authorization/) may be useful to you.

Comment: Our application tracks the medias of famous celebs and big companies can hire those celebs for digital promotion of their product. This use case can not work under basic permission. And we can not change the basic architecture because that would literally shut the product.

Comment: `Yeah, they grant public_content only to applications with some specific usage cases. ` Can you please provide some specific use case that you know would give us this permission.

Comment: I believe that we fall in point 3. My website is http://campaygn.com Please have a look once.

Comment: @NarayaN I am not an Instagram developer, so, it won't help if you look at your website :) Try to apply for review again, describe what your website does, and inform that you fall into the third category, and explain why.

Comment: I do agree with you. I just shared the page if you had more info. I am going to reapply once again with new words and more detailed explanation.

Comment: Hi, facing similar problem, how did the resubmitted review go?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable scopes invividually for your client `https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=APPC‌​ALLBACK&access_token=ACCESSTOKEN&response_type=code&scope=public_content` in your browser, using your values for the uppercase words? This should enable your registered client to work with the public_content scope.

`https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=xxxxx&redirect_uri=xxxxx&access_token=xxxxx&response_type=code&scope=public_content`

**your comment**

Read the error message, did you supply a valid client-id from your instagram developer account. Did you setup a redirect_uri for that client? Do you authenticate to instagram to get an access token?

This worked for me this weekend. Double check the values you set in the url and call it directly in your browser.

Comment: This does not work as it says `{"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", "error_message": "You must include a valid client_id, response_type, and redirect_uri parameters"}`

Comment: seems like you are not passing correct parameters to your api request

Comment: This is my URL looks like my friend `https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=http://xxxxxxxxx.com&access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&scope=public_content` All the xxxx are replaced with proper info.

Comment: might be missing the `&response_type=code` [parameter](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/). I'll update my answer

Comment: I have received a code.. I am trying with it.. Will soon update this comment

Comment: So it seems you got your public scope enabled?

Comment: No Mate.. That did not work... I still have the issue. I have resubmitted the app

Comment: @NarayaN, I think you're missing the `response_type` param.  Include `response_type=code`.  You should also remove the `access_token` param.  After all, you don't have that yet, right?  The whole point of this request is to obtain an access_token.  Finally, this is a server-side auth flow, right?  If this is client-side, you should use the implicit-auth flow

Comment: By Doing so it gets me a code but all the request's response is "The client has not approved this request".